# change KDE screen locker

Tags: kde, screen-lock

How can I change whatever program KDE5 uses for screen
locking to *slock*? AFAICS there is no such option in the
system settings.

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in way in KDE5. You'll have to disable the KDE screen locker, then manually run something to trigger `slock`. The method is similar to my answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/395152/18887), but I'll summarise below.

You can use something like `xss-lock` to automatically trigger the screensaver. You can start this automatically on login, by creating the following file at `~/.config/autostart/xss-lock.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Exec=xss-lock -- /path/to/slock &
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Name=slock_trigger
```

To change the timeout value, use

```
$ xset s TIME_IN_SECONDS TIME_IN_SECONDS
```

replacing `TIME_IN_SECONDS` with the number of seconds of idleness before you want it to activate. I don't entirely understand why you need to enter it twice, but that's what worked for me.