# How can I install asciiquarium as a screensaver?

Tags: screensaver

My beloved screensaver [Asciiquarium](http://www.robobunny.com/projects/asciiquarium/html/) is not available for KDE Plasma 5. It was previously available in [KDE Plasma 3](https://store.kde.org/content/show.php?content=29207) and Plasma 4, but Plasma 5 dropped support. How can I run Asciiquarium as a screensaver in any desktop environment?

[image: Asciiquarium screenshot]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Asciiquarium can run in a [fullscreen terminal, and the screen locked with xtrlock](https://www.reddit.com/r/i3wm/comments/60iysb/any_way_i_can_get_asciiquarium_as_a_lock_screen/). However the link is short on details.

Firstlly, I prefer [`alock`](https://github.com/Arkq/alock/) to `xtrlock`, since it provides some visual feedback on password entry, and can also hide the mouse cursor. N.B. `alock` requires a single keystroke first to start entry. After the green border appears,  type in your password.

The following script is used to activate the screensaver, and is located at `~/.local/bin/asciiquarium_screensaver`

```
#!/bin/sh
xterm -fullscreen -bg black -e asciiquarium & alock -cursor none -bg none; xdotool key --clearmodifiers q
```

The first part launches `xterm` in fullscreen, runs `asciiquarium`, and places it in the background (`&`). `-bg black` is necessary to avoid the background of xterm showing as a border behind `asciiquarium` itself.

`alock` immediately runs, hiding the cursor (`-cursor none`) and locking the screen transparently (`-bg none`). When `alock` is unlocked by the user, it quits. `xdotool` then types <kbd>q</kbd>, which will quit `asciiquarium` and hence `xterm`.

Now all that remains is to automatically trigger the screensaver with something like `xss-lock`. To start it automatically on login, create the following file at `~/.config/autostart/xss-lock.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Exec=xss-lock -- /home/sparhawk/.local/bin/asciiquarium_screensaver &
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Name=asciiquarium_screensaver
```

To change the timeout value, use

```
$ xset s TIME_IN_SECONDS TIME_IN_SECONDS
```

replacing `TIME_IN_SECONDS` with the number of seconds of idleness before you want it to activate. I don't entirely understand why you need to enter it twice, but that's what worked for me.